# Is there a tool that can display a SVN repository visually ( i.e. pretty charts )?

Tags: svn

Real strange.

I cannot find a tool that enables one to display a SVN repository in graphical form.
I would like the ability to see changes in revision / time , branch / time graphs.

Does anyone know of one. **Ideally it would be platform neutral or even better web based**.

Solutions offered so far in brief:

- svn-graph
- [Fisheye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) ( you want how
  much !£?* )

Comment: Thanks for asking this, i found something i needed! =)

Comment: Fisheye is not so bad for small projects; a one off $10 for up to five users.  After that, it jumps to $1,000, but, again, athat's a one  off payment.

Comment: svn-graph now redirects to a dating site.

Comment: This whole page is a great example of why software recommendations are off topic on SO.

Answer (score 13):

[Fisheye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/), from Atlassian, looks at an SVN repository and can show you a few graphs. Also provides a handy web interface for blame, diff, etc.

for example, some sample images at [one of the demo servers:](http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/chart/~charttype=Pie,stacktype=Author,extn=.java,extn=.js,extn=.jsp,extn=.xml/google-guice)

1. [image: pie chart]
2. [image: line change]

And if you like some pretty code metrics, [here are some samples](http://fisheye6.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/code-metrics/ofbiz).

Comment: For those prices? No.

Comment: Those prices are a one-time $0 for up to 5 users. More than that and it jumps to $1,000, which sounds a lot, but A) it a one time payment B) unlimited users. So, yes, it sucks if there are 6 of you, but a large organization can certainly afford it

Answer (score 7):

You might also give [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/downloads.html) a try.

It's written in Java (meets your platform-neutral requirement) and generates a static html tree with your revision history and commit graphs. You can use Ant or a batch file to automate the process of calling it.

I've also heard good things about Trac.

Answer (score 6):

for simplicity, [tortoise svn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) gives a basic revision graph

Answer (score 6):

I am writing subverion statistics graph generation utility named [SVNPlot](https://bitbucket.org/nitinbhide/svnplot/). It is inspired by the graphs generated by StatSVN.  However, the SVNPlot graph generation is in two steps (a) first it creates a [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/) database from the subversion log information (b) actual graphs are then generated by extracting the database sqlite database (using simple sql queries).

I think using sql to extract the graph data from the log information is resulting in greater flexibility and good performance. Right now the SVNPlot only generates graphs but it very easy to extract any other stats from the generated sqlite database.

SVNPlot is written in python and it uses excellent [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) package to generate the graphs. The code is available on [SVNPlot](https://bitbucket.org/nitinbhide/svnplot/) page on google code (license is New BSD license). The sample graphs generated for Rietveld repository are available at http://thinkingcraftsman.in/projects/svnplot/index.htm

Comment: You should've quoted your answer text since it is copied from `svnplot`'s wiki and provided a link to the original source found [here](https://code.google.com/p/svnplot/wiki/Introduction).

Answer (score 4):

The only tool that I've ever encountered is the [svn-graph.pl](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/svn-graph.pl) perl script from the svn tools. It spits out a [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) dot file which can be rendered in a variety of image formats. This could be wrapped up in a cgi script to form a basic web graph tool.

Answer (score 3):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is a wiki and issue tracking tool, which happens to include an SVN browser.
The [RevtreePlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/RevtreePlugin), for Trac will allow you to display your repo in a graphical form.
Trac is still a very young application(latest version is 0.11.1), but we use it at work for our software development and it's proved very useful so far.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could elaborate a little on what "visual display" and "pretty
charts" you are after?

A roundabout way would be to clone the svn repository with [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn), then you can use the graphical [gitk](http://lwn.net/Articles/140350/) or [giggle](http://developer.imendio.com/projects/giggle) tools on it to visualize branches and merging as well as browsing the specifics.

(You would then get the distributed thing, that [git](http://git.or.cz/) does so well, as a nice side effect.)

Comment: The giggle link gives a 404.

I might also suggest that SourceTree visualizes Git really well if you decide to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracGuide) includes a source code browser and limited statistics analysis.  It's web-based, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There is also nice application [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/features/) with nice graph.
But version with graph is not free.

Answer (score 1):

There is also https://github.com/justinmassiot/svn-graph-branches. Although no activity since 2010 and it didn't work for me (not compatible with my dot version).

Answer (score -2):

You could also try [MPY SVN STATS](http://mpy-svn-stats.berlios.de/). [Here](http://mpy-svn-stats.berlios.de/zope-stats/) is an example graph for Zope.