# SVN - Software to Produce Graphs, Stats and pretty pictures concerning the evolution of a system

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a tool that can display a SVN repository visually ( i.e. pretty charts )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039/is-there-a-tool-that-can-display-a-svn-repository-visually-i-e-pretty-charts)

I have a google code project which I used SVN to update. I am about to submit the project as the deliverable for a thesis on producing resource intensive applications on a mobile platform.

I was wondering if any of you knew of software which I could point at my repository in order to get stats for say lines of code over time? Number of classes over time?

Something like that anyway.

It's an Android project and so uses *.java files mainly.

Kind regards,

Gavin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are in a Java project you could use [Sonar](http://sonar.codehaus.org/) which is an very cool open source project which not only shows statistics of lines of code but some other useful stats as method complexity, tests covering, compliance with code rules among many others. It has a *demo instance* called [Nemo](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/) using Apache projects for you to browse its features. Here a screenshot of the *Time machine* report:

[Sonar time machine screenshot http://nemo.sonarsource.org/charts/trends/60175?sids=1024412,1025601,1026859,1073764,1348107,2255284&metrics=complexity,mandatory_violations_density,lines,coverage&format=png&ts=1244661473034](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/charts/trends/60175?sids=1024412,1025601,1026859,1073764,1348107,2255284&metrics=complexity,mandatory_violations_density,lines,coverage&format=png&ts=1244661473034)

I'm pretty sure you'll find many useful info using this software!

*Foot note: You're in the right track by using SCM since school, well done!*

Answer (score 2):

Since your project is open source with a repository that's accessible, just add your project to [Ohloh](https://www.ohloh.net/).

After you've added your project and repository url there, wait a few minutes (depending on how big your repository is) and you'll get nice graphs like [these](https://www.ohloh.net/p/subversion/analyses/latest).

Answer (score 1):

[ConQAT](http://conqat.cs.tum.edu/index.php/ConQAT) will produce some of that, and can then be hooked to a database for storage.  ConQAT has the advantage of being free.

Also free for you, I believe, is [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/).  It can produce some of what you want automatically and I just extended mine to add some custom graphs for source by file type.  A simple batch file is building a teamcity-info.xml, which TeamCity will interpret for me.  A couple of config changes later to main-settings.xml and *project*/plugin-settings.xml and I get graphs over time.

You could easily write a batch file to count lines per file, or count lines per file excluding comment-only lines.

EDIT:  I don't know how I missed the "point at my repository" part of your question.  For my answers to work you'd have to checkout each revision, run the stats, repeat.  Sorry.

Comment: Really good info still, I guess I was just being lazy, I was hoping I could pass my SVN details to a third party app that would check read only stuff out and do what you have described.

I can probably write something to do that based on your info, cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

[StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) Does at least some of what you want.  I don't think it will do anything that requires understanding the source, but it will do line and file-based stats.

Answer (score 0):

take a look on [code swarm](http://code.google.com/p/codeswarm)

[here](http://www.vimeo.com/1093745) is demonstration based on python project repository activity

if you're interested, 
[here](http://code.google.com/p/codeswarm/wiki/GeneratingAVideo) are instructions on generating video