# what can i use to create a revision tree graphic on linux

Tags: linux, svn, tree, graph, revision

Which tool should I use in order to create a revision tree for a whole svn repository on linux. It's going to be like a visualization of every action made on that repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) should be a good starting point for the graph drawing part. Also http://code.google.com/p/svngraph/ might already be a working solution. Other pointers might be found in this question: [Is there a tool that can display a SVN repository visually ( i.e. pretty charts )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039/is-there-a-tool-that-can-display-a-svn-repository-visually-i-e-pretty-charts)

Comment: Very powerful tool that matches the given needs.