# Free graphical tool to manage software versions

Tags: svn, version-control

Currently i use a MS Powerpoint file to track subversion tag names, branches and merges using lines and text boxes. I only want to keep track and display the svn tag names, branch names and revision numbers. Do not want a cluttered display.

Is there a good free tool that can store this type of version control information and display the data in a graphical way to track upgrade paths, etc.?

Either a tool that interfaces to the subversion server directly or a standalone tool where the data is input manually - either would be good - better than managing via MS Powerpoint file.

screenshot of ppt file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdPMc.png

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can try to use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) and build [graph](http://tortoisesvn.net/bigpicture.html#revisiongraph).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to automate the process, there are tools out there that can do that for you, like **[svn-graph-branches](http://code.google.com/p/svn-graph-branches/)**.

Note: this question has **[already been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039/is-there-a-tool-that-can-display-a-svn-repository-visually-i-e-pretty-charts)**.